# FailSafe plugin is not running feature files in parallel

Tags: maven, junit, parallel-processing, cucumber, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have included failsafe plugin with parallel methods and threadcount 4. And framework is cucumber with junit. I'm trying to run features in parallel with failsafe plugin of maven. i have different profiles for different environments and use maven verify goal with command

```
verify -D environment=int
```

```xml
<profile>
    <id>int</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>environment</name>
            <value>int</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <env.info>int</env.info>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <Env>${env.info}</Env>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>3</threadCount>
                            <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/TestRunner*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

My test runner class is defined like this

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/feature/"},
        glue = {"com.stepdefinition"},
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/report.html",
                "json:target/json/report.json",
                "rerun:target/rerun.txt"},
         tags = "@continuousDataloggerLineChartInt or @trendLineChartInt or @standardDataloggerLineChartInt",
        dryRun = false
)

public class TestRunner {
}
```

features folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

issue is build is successful and tests are running but not in parallel mode.

what can I do here?

Comment: i have figured out issue ...transitive dependecies are there in pom.xml

Comment: may I get the solution as I am facing the exact same issue. Thanks